# Can a compact curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be characterised by the image of some analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, curves, analyticity

Given a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is non-intersecting and of finite length, more formally it is the image of an injective function $f(t):[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ with arc length $\int_0^1||f'(t)||dt<\infty$, can I give an alternative characterisation of the curve as the image of a real analytic function $g(t)$?

Comment: No, not even if $f$ is $C^\infty$. If $g(t)$ is real analytic all of its values are completely determined by its values on an arbitrarily small neighborhood of any fixed $t$, but values of $f$ can be manipulated almost at will using [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Smooth_partitions_of_unity). [Analytic curves](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Analytic_curve) are a small subset of smooth curves.

Comment: Can you see why it won't work for $f(t) = \begin{cases} t^2\sin(1/t), & t>0 \\ 0, & t=0 \end{cases}$?

Comment: Thank you, you've both been very helpful.